# Creating a custom .vimrc gives me an E216 error on opening vim

Tags: unix, vim, zos

I am trying to set ignorecase by default in my vim environment.

Curently, `~/.vimrc` doesn't exist. When I open vim and use `:scriptnames` to see what scripts are loaded, I have a bunch of `*.vim` files loaded.

When I create my own `~/.vimrc` containing only:

```
set ic
```

I get the following error:

> E216: No such group or event: SpellFileMissing * call
>   spellfile#LoadFile(expand('')) Hit ENTER or type command to
>   continue

when opening vim. When I use `:scriptnames` to see what scripts are loaded again, on top of the list is my '.vimrc' file followed by all the same '*.vim' files as before...

Why would this happen?

Thanks...

P.S. I am using vim version 6.3

Answer (score 1):

This looks like a mismatch of (newer) Vim runtime files and your ancient Vim version; the `SpellFileMissing` event is related to spell checking, which was introduced in Vim 7.0. You seem to have runtime files that initialize the (non-existing) spell checking.

Upgrading Vim looks like the easiest and best way to resolve this.

Vim 6.3 is from 2004 and *very* outdated. It should be possible to install the latest version 7.3; if you can't find a proper package for your distribution (for Windows, check the binaries from the [Cream project](http://sourceforge.net/projects/cream/files/Vim/), it's also not very difficult to [compile](http://www.vim.org/download.php) (e.g. from the Mercurial sources) on Linux.

Comment: Yes, this fixed the problem, thanks! However, I still don't understand how that message didn't come up before. Only when I created my own .vimrc file that has nothing to do with 'SpellFileMissing'

Comment: Vim's default behavior is to run in "compatible mode" when it doesn't find a `~/.vimrc`. Because you created a `~/.vimrc`, Vim is now running in "nocompatible mode". That `autocmd` may be executed within a feature check and trying to use an event that is not available is your medieval build.